# Lock screen - password incorrect

Tags: upgrade, login, password, lock-screen

I have upgraded Ubuntu to 12.04 and now I have a problem in logging in after locking the screen: it says the password is incorrect even though I provide the valid password. I found a temporary solution by switching users and logging in again with the same user.

Comment: I'd report a bug if anybody can reproduce it. If you can reproduce it, drop a comment...

Comment: Having the same issue... on Ubuntu Mate 18.04... oddly this only occurred on my laptop after a clean install... I have installed other machines, including my desktop and there I've never had the issue... strange! I'll try the suggestion flagged as "accepted answer".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same issue.  It is likely the ownership is wrong for `/etc/shadow` (See section "gnome-screensaver authentication failure with incorrect `/etc/shadow permissions`" of [this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingScreenLocking)).

You need to `sudo chown root:shadow /etc/shadow` then `sudo chmod u=r,g=r /etc/shadow` See [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/600631/comments/7).

The interesting question is "Why ownership changed?". Because I don't remember changing it.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me! For some unknown reason, the group ownership was "root" instead of "shadow" for /etc/shadow on my laptop. Resetting the group ownership to "shadow" solved the issue :-)

Answer (score 5):

I could resolve this issue with the following permission changes:

```
sudo chown root:shadow /etc/gshadow
sudo chown root:shadow /etc/gshadow-
sudo chown root:shadow /etc/shadow
sudo chown root:shadow /etc/shadow-
```

Found here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1006366

Comment: Albeit less informative as the answer above, this is also a correct answer, thanks! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem on Ubuntu 16.04. Found the solution in http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1006366 (linked in [fret](https://askubuntu.com/users/260842/fret)'s answer):

```
chmod 2755 /sbin/unix_chkpwd
```

In my case, `unix_chkpwd` had lost its [setgid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#GUID) bit when I copied my entire filesystem to a new machine using tar.

Answer (score -1):

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I had the same issue

By mistake I ran a chown on the root filesystem (Yikes!) and since then I started having the issue described here.

I ran the command given in oshobov's answer, but that did not work for me, but using my own account instead of root made it work.

```
sudo chown your-username:shadow /etc/shadow
```

Comment: `/etc/shadow` must not be owned by any other account than root!