# After I log off it displays "wrong password" when I try to log in again

Tags: login

When I log off my system and after some time try to log back in it displays "wrong password". I need to go to "switch user" and there select my username and then I can enter my password and log in. But, it doesn't open directly from the log off screen.

Comment: Check the link http://askubuntu.com/questions/128785/lock-screen-password-incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Needed to change group to shadow:

```
sudo chown root:shadow /etc/gshadow
sudo chown root:shadow /etc/shadow
```

I got the solution from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/512070/361549)