# lock screen - correct password refused

Tags: password, lock-screen

Ubuntu 16.04.2  Screensaver blanks, then locks screen.  wiggle mouse, get password prompt, but it wont accept correct password.  Only recourse is a) reboot or b) switch user, log back in with same user/password.  I have followed the suggested fixes [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128785/lock-screen-password-incorrect), but no joy, same result.

Comment: You said you followed that link , which of them did you follow?

Comment: I did the following:sudo chown root:shadow /etc/gshadow
sudo chown root:shadow /etc/gshadow-
sudo chown root:shadow /etc/shadow
sudo chown root:shadow /etc/shadow- the gshadow and shaow files were all set as root:root before, but the fix made no difference. The checkpaswd was correct already.

Comment: Did you verify that the keyboard layout on the lock screen is correct, i. e. the same as on the log-in screen?