# Cannot unlock screen after manual lock in Ubuntu 17.04 with Unity

Tags: login, password, encryption, 17.04, lock-screen

I have recently reinstalled Ubuntu 17.04 on a new laptop using full disk encryption, having forgotten to enable it the first time.
To save some time on configuration, I created a backup of my home complete directory and restored it in the new installation.

When I start the laptop I can login without any problem, but if the session get's locked I can't log back in again as usual and I get a "wrong password" message.

Using the terminal via CTRL+ALT+F1 accepts the password every time. It also works as a workaround to click "Change User" in the graphical session and then log back in.
I haven't yet found any useful information in any log files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that a misguided try to restore the backupped /etc direcory caused the error. as [Lock screen - password incorrect](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128785/lock-screen-password-incorrect) suggests, the /etc/gshadow and /etc/shadow were owned by `root:root` instead of `root:shadow`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in **lightdm**, you can't switch the keyboard layout, it is showing you that you are switching the layout, but in fact you are not. I found this accidentally, I noticed that this problem appears only when I forget my computer in any other language except English. I used to do **CTR+ALT+F2**(my computer is ASUS, in your case it might be **CTR+ALT+F1** ) to enter the terminal, to disable the screensaver after login with the command:
 **gnome-screensaver-command -d** and to go back **CTR+ALT+F7**
After doing this, I was able to continue my job, without losing any unsaved work. Now, thanks to the previous answer given here by the user QooP, I am using **gdm3**, not the **lightdm**, and I hope that the bug will be fixed soon...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 18.04 + Gnome desktop + **lightdm**.

But initially, I switched back to gnome from unity and left lightdm as is, so when I had second language enabled and lock the screen it seems that Ubuntu didn't switch language to English properly. So I managed to create additional user with digits-only password to reset my main account password when it happens.

Then I though that display manager may be the issue, so I've switched back to gdm3 and all worked normally.

(trying to be more clear, probably I'll try to reproduce that)

1. Install Ubuntu 18.04
2. sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop
3. select lightdm as a default window manager
4. return back to gnome
5. switch keyboard to the second language
6. lock the screen by Win+L
7. Password is incorrect
8. **sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3**, choose gdm3, reboot or re-login
9. lock screen in any active keyboard language
10. Password working as a charm

If I'm not the only one, that should be reported to Ubuntu bugs, surely