# Need to enter password 5 to 10 times at logon screen after intsalling lightdm

Tags: login, lightdm

Hi I am sorry but I do not have much knowledge on Linux or Ubuntu OSs.  I installed a fresh copy of 18.04 LTS and upgraded to 20.04 LTS.

I have an NVIDIA RTX 2080 and installed the NVIDIA Drivers using the additional Drivers tab in software updates.

Everything was working fine until I install the remote connectivity software I wanted to install. When I use it I can connect to the remote Ubuntu system but I only get a black screen and a mouse. I was working with Vendor to get that resolved and we installed lightdm as a fix.

Now the remote software connection works fine but when I get to logon screen using the system locally, I need to enter the password 5 to 10 times before it will let me logon.

After entering password the screen goes black for a second then changes the login background for a second then goes right back to logon screen.  If I repeat the password it eventually will let me in.

I am able to press ctrl + Alt + F3 logon using CLI and then do startx but I don't get why the GUI logon doesn't work.

Can anyone help a complete Noob at Linux why this is happening? I tried searching for it and see people have been having a similar issue for years and everyone has a different fix but none of them seemed to work for me.

I keep having to re-image my system cause I break it cause I don't know what I am doing lol

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

So, this bug is still not fixed...Please, read here
[login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/962583/cannot-unlock-screen-after-manual-lock-in-ubuntu-17-04-with-unity/1159858#1159858)
and use **gdm3** instead of **lightdm** I hope this answer helps you.

Best regards

Comment: This answer could be improved by linking "this bug" to the appropriate bug report. It eliminates confusion for future readers -- they can see exactly which bug you are referring to, and if this answer is still appropriate for them.

Comment: due to issues with gdm3 and the NVIDIA driver and the remote assistance software I am using I am not able to use gdm3.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was using the NVIDIA proprietary driver too, but it was causing me a lot of other troubles and I stopped. What kind of a remote software do you mean?